# Adding custom view from XIB to scrollview iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to load the `UIView` from **xib** and add it the `UIScrollView` 
 I added constraints in xib but constraints  are breaking 
I am not able to set the frame of view.

Here is the my code

```
let nibContents =  Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TokenView", owner: nil, options: nil)
let view  = nibContents![0] as! TokenView
view.frame = CGRect(x:x, y:y, width:size.width+30 , height:30)
scrollview.addSubview(view)
```

Comment: whree you called this in didload or else ,

Comment: try to call this lines in viewDidLayoutSubviews method.

Comment: I have scrollview inside tableviewCell, In cellForRowAt method I am calling function to add views to scrollview

Comment: than try to call those lines in layoutSubviews method of tableviewcell.

Comment: if still constraint breaking than identify which constraint is breaking.

Comment: Thank you . It worked for me when I moved my code to layoutSubviews in tableviewcell